# coundown minutes in angularjs or javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, countdown

Hello i want to create a simple script to run a countdown who start at 05:00 and finish at 00:00. I need help please. I can not find a script that works. Ive tested with function new Date() but i get a format like this Days/Hours/Minutes/Seconds and me i need only Minutes/Seconds. When the countdown is finished an alert appears with a message and the countdown is stopped at 00:00.

For the moment I've this:

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.carname = "Volvo";
    $scope.timer = timer();
    
    function timer() {
     var minutes = "03";
     var secondes = "00";
     var init = minutes + ":" + secondes;
      var res = document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = init;
      return res;
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

<h1>{{carname}}</h1>
<h4 id="timer">{{timer()}}</h4>

</div>
```

Comment: did the answer help?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you can simply use **[`$interval`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock/service/$interval)** function and use a **`custom filter`** to display it in seconds

**`$interval(function(){console.log($scope.counter--)},1000);`**

**DEMO**

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $interval) {
    $scope.carname = "Volvo";   
     $scope.counter = 180;   
     $interval(function(){console.log($scope.counter--)},1000);
});
app.filter('counter', [function() {
    return function(seconds) {
        return new Date(1970, 0, 1).setSeconds(seconds);
    };
}])
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
<h1>{{carname}}</h1>
{{counter | counter | date:'mm:ss'}}
</div>
```

Comment: Good thank you. And now how i add a stop when countdown is finished (0:00) please?

Answer (score 1):

I took an example from [here](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_countdown.asp), slightly modified and here it is:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<style>
p {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 60px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
// Set the date we're counting down to
var countDownDate = new Date().setMinutes(new Date().getMinutes()+5);

// Update the count down every 1 second
var x = setInterval(function() {

    // Get todays date and time
    var now = new Date().getTime();

    // Find the distance between now an the count down date
    var distance = countDownDate - now;

    // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
    var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
    var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
    var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
    var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

    // Output the result in an element with id="demo"
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = days + "d " + hours + "h "
    + minutes + "m " + seconds + "s ";

    // If the count down is over, write some text 
    if (distance < 0) {
        clearInterval(x);
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "EXPIRED";
    }
}, 1000);
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple example about countdown function using 'let' variable:

```
function countDown(time) {
  for(let i  = time; i >= 0; i--){
    setTimeout(function () {
      console.log(i);
    },(time - i) * 1000);
  }
}
countDown(5);
```

Here is a simple example about countdown recursion function using 'var' variable and:

```
function countDown2(time){
  for(var i  = time; i >= 0; i--){
      setTimeout(function () {
        console.log(time);
        time--;
      },(time-i)*1000);
    }
}
countDown2(5);
```